# Can I use axios (and other npm libraries) in Nativescript Vue?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I would like to develop an android app in Nativescript, but am I safe to assume that aside from the view layer, which uses its own components, everything else, like the logic, will be the same as when I write a vuejs pwa?

And that logic can use other npm libraries such as axios and my other custom build ES5 based plugins?

Answer (score 0):

No. Although NativeScript embeds JavaScript engines for Android and iOS, similar to nodejs or Chromium, it does not implement the node specification, nor does it have the same base node modules (fs, crypto, http, net, etc.)

Many of the npm packages' implementations depend implicitly on node's API. You would want to skim through the npm library's code to verify that the package does not use such APIs in order to be sure that the application will work.